# Application breaks when json file is requested

Tags: reactjs, node.js, ajax, express, browser

I have setup a simple express server that serves static files (React app build) like shown below:

```
import express from 'express'
import path from 'path'

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../dist')))
app.use('/locales_phrase', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../locales_phrase')))

app.listen(3000)
```

React app tries to import `json` file from server, which is successfully imported (200 status code in network, with application/json response type). But application is not rendered throwing following error:

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/json". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec (pointing to that json file

But if I remove that import of json app start up fine.
Javascript is received with `application/javascript` response type in both cases